# Есть ли способы восстановления только определенной таблицы из бекапа?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, имеется огромная БД и файл бекапа к ней.

Что-то пошло не так и некоторые таблицы были испорчены.

Можно ли не палить из пушки по воробьям и из файла *.bak забрать определенные таблицы, не восстанавливая всю БД, что может быть очень время затратно?

Если нет, то по какой причине эта полезная возможность отсутсвует?

Про логи транзакций я знаю, но в данном вопросе я рассматриваю взятие из бекапа определенного куска.

Comment: Таблицы восстанавливать не получится. Но можно восстанавливать страницы, если получится понять, какие нужны. Однажды мы шли по такому пути, но работа выполнялось не мной, по этому процесс я понял плохо. Возможно эта статья на хабре сможет вам помочь https://habrahabr.ru/post/137301/

Answer (score 3):

Нет. возможности нет. Бекап от SQL это не просто набор структур и данных, это фактически дамп всей структуры базы данных с индексами и прочим, с сохранением фактического расположения данных. Т.е. физически данные в таблице могут быть размазаны по всему бекапу.
К тому же, как вы представляете себе восстановление одной таблицы, в какую структуру она должна попасть? Если пробовать восстанавливать в текущей базе, получаются проблемы целостности (ключи, индексы), если создать отдельную и в ней создать только эту таблицу — это уж очень специфическая задача получается.

Для вашего случая могу предложить такие варианты: посмотреть на программы, которые пытаются сделать recovery данных по испорченным бекапам (которые самостоятельно анализируют структуру бекапа), или восстановить бекап в соседнюю базу данных (можно на другом сервере), и достать нужные вам данные.

Answer (score 3):

Такой возможности в SQL Server нет.

По какой причине - вопрос не к сообществу, а к Microsoft. Могу лишь сделать предположение, что причина в том, что бэкап делается не потаблично, а постранично, т.е. в бэкапе нет легкодоступных метаданных с информацией о том, на каких именно страницах хранится ваша таблица и какие страницы необходимо восстановить. Кроме того, если вдруг окажется, что в вашей базе страница поменяла владельца и на ней размещается уже не таблица, а какой-либо другой объект, то нужно прорабатывать дополнительную логику восстановления - когда страница восстанавливается не на свое же место, а на новое, с изменением структуры данных (нужно поменять все ссылки на эту страницу).

По всей видимости, Microsoft считает такую работу нецелесообразной, поэтому единственный вариант частичного восстановления - это восстановление файлов, файловых групп и отдельных страниц.

Comment: Поправил сам себя - можно еще восстанавливать отдельные страницы.