# Как извлечь из базы mysql отдельный таблицы?

Tags: mysql

На рабочем столе есть бэкап рабочей базы данных.
На сервере есть старая версия БД без тех записей в таблицах, что есть в первой.

Полностью импортировать базу на сервер не получается, так как он ругается на ошибки в отдельных таблицах, информация в которых как раз мне не нужна.

Чем открыть файл `sql` и сохранить из него таблицы в отдельный пригодный для последующего импорта `sql` файл?
У кого есть подобный опыт, подскажите с какой программой работаете?

Comment: Бэкап из какой СУБД? MySQL или SQL Server?

Comment: *Чем открыть файлик sql и сохранить из него таблицы в отдельный пригодный для последующего импорта sql файл?* Любой текстовый редактор, способный открыть файл (дампы обычно пухлые, и это может оказаться проблемой). Я лично использую для сверхбольших текстов EditPadLite (не сочтите рекламой)... А если бэкап от MS Sql - то см. напр. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585342

Comment: @matrix Бэкап сайта из mysql ну расширение бд - sql, соответственно

Comment: @Akina любой то любой, но бд действие пухлая,  и обычный блокнот виснет, может быть думаю есть специальный редактор, где таблицы имеют понятный и возможно даже приятный к mysql  вид

Comment: А пробовали бэкап развернуть в новую пустую БД? Ошибки при импорте видимо из-за того, что пытаетесь в существующую структуру развернуть.

Comment: @matrix именно в новую и заливал. Да и на будущее полезно будет знать как заливать отдельные части базы, а не тащить сотни мб за собой ради таблиц в несколько кб

Comment: Блокнот в качестве редактора для подобных операций не рассматривается даже теоретически. EditPadLite я специально отобрал именно по этому параметру - способности нормально работать с многогигабайтными текстовыми файлами, в т.ч. на порядок превышающими по размеру оперативку, без заметной деградации производительности системы.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов А текст ошибок секретен?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov нет перед глазами,  уже завтра буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

notepad++ используйте, например

Comment: Слабоват он. Полгига - уже со скрипом, два гига -  совсем увы...

Comment: по хорошему конечно через любой менеджер баз данных sql файл можно открыть а-ля MS SQL Managment или mysql management studio

Comment: можно кстати еще использовать log viewer проги - они и по 5 Гб умеют открывать. Есть еще вариант sublime text - тоже может осилить 2 Гб